# Передача полей в биндинг тригеров WPF

Tags: wpf

Возникла задача по передачи строки в строку (по определенному индексу) из другого элемента формы. То есть существует строка в TextBlock - "Имя _ Фамилия_" где по индексу символов "_" из элемента TextBox должны передаваться значения.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="12" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Имя_ Фамилия_"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxSection}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value=""></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
```

Вопрос: Как указать на индекса в форме для триггера изменений в содержимом TextBlock?

Comment: Ничего не понял. Но xaml строки резать не умеет, потребуется конвертер или что-то ещё

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, нужно было именно резать строку, влепил подряд несколько блоков впритык и решил вопрос